# Cakephp Model with multiple status

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, has-many

I'm asking myself something... Here is the question :

I have a model Request. This model has a status. (let's say it is an integer)

As the status will change through the time **AND** as I want to keep a record of each changes this was pretty clear in my mind that the status will not be a field of the Request table/model.

I thought I will add a table/model RequestStatus and say to CakePHP

`Request` hasMany `RequestStatus`

Then I thought that it will be simple to retrieve all the Request that has a valid status only.

But I was wrong.

**Using containable is not good as it retrieve the Request even if they have a wrong status (or even if they don't have a status).**

So, I tested 2 solutions :

- Binding on the fly the RequestStatus model as a hasOne relation but
  it not works as expected
- Use a joins key/array when making my find call.

There is clearly something that I missed because, this is not working.

Am I missing something ? Or the best way to do it is by having a status field in the Request table ?

**EDIT :** What I forgot to mention is that I need to use this query with the pagination of CakePHP

Answer (score 0):

I will assume a couple of things you didn't mention. First of all, I suppose you also created a `RequestStatus belongsTo Request` relationship. And I imagine your RequestStatus table have four columns: `id`, `status`, `request_id` and `created`. The `request_id` column is the foreign key and `created` is the magic field that CakePHP populates when a new row is created. I also assume you are using Containable behaviour.

With that, you can go three different ways:

**1) You can retrieve last valid Statuses along with their Requests.**

In your RequestModel:

```
public function getValidRequests() {
    $db = $this->RequestStatus->getDataSource();

    $subquery = $db->buildStatement(array(
        'fields' => array('request_id', 'max(created) as lastcreated'),
        'table' => $db->fullTableName($this->RequestStatus),
        'alias' => 'temp',
        'group' => array('request_id')
    ), $this->RequestStatus);

    return $this->RequestStatus->find('all', array(
        'contain' => array('Request'),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => '(' . $subquery . ')',
                'alias' => 'rs2',
                'type' => 'right',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'RequestStatus.request_id = rs2.request_id',
                    'RequestStatus.created = rs2.lastcreated'
                )
            )
        ),
        'conditions' => array('RequestStatus.status' => 1),
        'order' => array('RequestStatus.request_id' => 'desc')
    ));
}
```

**2) You can retrieve all Requests with their Status, then return only those with last valid status.**

In your RequestModel:

```
public function getValidRequests() {
    $requests = $this->find('all', array(
        'contain' => array(
            'RequestStatus' => array(
                'order' => array('RequestStatus.created' => 'desc')
            )
        )
    ));
    $result = array();
    foreach ($requests as $request) {
        if ($request['RequestStatus'][0]['status'] == 1)
            $result[] = $request;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**3) Denormalization.**

Add a `last_status` column in your `Request` table. So every time you update a request's status, insert that new status into your `RequestStatus` table and save that new status to `Request.last_status`. Now you can simply do:

```
public function getValidRequests() {
    return $this->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Request.last_status' => 1)
    ));
}
```

Comment: @azerto00 After re-reading my answer, I found that method #1 is not going to return what you need. Maybe better use `having` instead of `conditions`, because the filter is made after order and group are made. I'll edit it.

Comment: I will try that tomorrow and will answer tomorrow. Thanks !

Comment: What I forgot to mention is that I need to use this query with the pagination of CakePHP

Comment: @azerto00 Then you should use either method #1 or #3, because method #2 uses a hasMany relationship and CakePHP makes 2 queries to build the result array in that case.

Comment: Solution #1 seems to work, but I'm not able to order by Request.id in this case. But I want the request ordered by id so If I change order by Request.id, it will not get the last RequestStatus. Am I right ?

Comment: @azerto00 You have to use subqueries. I edited #1. It should work now.